# No module named 'django_heroku'

Tags: python-3.x, django, heroku

I am trying to migrate my database to Heroku through:

`heroku run python3 manage.py migrate`

and I get this error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  `File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 328, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 366, in execute
    self.check()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 392, in check
    all_issues = self._run_checks(
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 63, in _run_checks
    issues = run_checks(tags=[Tags.database])
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 72, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/checks/database.py", line 9, in check_database_backends
    for conn in connections.all():
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 222, in all
    return [self[alias] for alias in self]
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 219, in __iter__
    return iter(self.databases)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 153, in databases
    self._databases = settings.DATABASES
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 76, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 63, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 142, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/app/learning_log/settings.py", line 134, in <module>
    import django_heroku
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django_heroku'
`

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()


    File "manage.py", line 17, in main
        execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
      File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
        utility.execute()
      File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 395, in execute
        self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
      File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 341, in run_from_argv
        connections.close_all()
      File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 225, in close_all
        for alias in self:
      File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 219, in __iter__
        return iter(self.databases)
      File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 48, in __get__
        res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
      File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 153, in databases
        self._databases = settings.DATABASES
      File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 76, in __getattr__
        self._setup(name)
      File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 63, in _setup
        self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
      File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 142, in __init__
        mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
      File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
        return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
      File "/app/learning_log/settings.py", line 134, in <module>
        import django_heroku
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django_heroku'
```

Here as well is my requirements.txt file content:

```
    asgiref==3.2.7
beautifulsoup4==4.9.1
bleach==3.1.5
certifi==2020.4.5.2
chardet==3.0.4
dj-database-url==0.5.0
Django==3.0.6
django-bootstrap4==2.0.1
django-heroku==0.3.1
docutils==0.16
gunicorn==20.0.4
idna==2.9
keyring==21.2.1
packaging==20.4
pkginfo==1.5.0.1
psycopg2==2.8.5
psycopg2-binary==2.8.5
Pygments==2.6.1
pyparsing==2.4.7
pytz==2020.1
readme-renderer==26.0
requests==2.24.0
requests-toolbelt==0.9.1
six==1.15.0
soupsieve==2.0.1
sqlparse==0.3.1
tqdm==4.46.1
twine==3.1.1
urllib3==1.25.9
webencodings==0.5.1
whitenoise==5.1.0
```

I am new to Python Django and Heroku, I don't understand as you can see the packages is installed on my file as well as in my settings.py as I imported the module and wrote this command:

```
import django_heroku
django_heroku.settings(locals())
```

That is what I get when I run heroku logs:

```
2020-06-18T23:28:32.458372+00:00 app[web.1]: self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
2020-06-18T23:28:32.458372+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 142, in __init__
2020-06-18T23:28:32.458373+00:00 app[web.1]: mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
2020-06-18T23:28:32.458373+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
2020-06-18T23:28:32.458374+00:00 app[web.1]: return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
2020-06-18T23:28:32.458374+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
2020-06-18T23:28:32.458375+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
2020-06-18T23:28:32.458375+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
2020-06-18T23:28:32.458376+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
2020-06-18T23:28:32.458376+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
2020-06-18T23:28:32.458377+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
2020-06-18T23:28:32.458377+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/learning_log/settings.py", line 134, in <module>
2020-06-18T23:28:32.458378+00:00 app[web.1]: import django_heroku
2020-06-18T23:28:32.458378+00:00 app[web.1]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django_heroku'
2020-06-18T23:28:32.458490+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-06-18 23:28:32 +0000] [9] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 9)
2020-06-18T23:28:32.515167+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-06-18 23:28:32 +0000] [10] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
2020-06-18T23:28:32.515191+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2020-06-18T23:28:32.515204+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 583, in spawn_worker
2020-06-18T23:28:32.515206+00:00 app[web.1]: worker.init_process()
2020-06-18T23:28:32.515206+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 119, in init_process
2020-06-18T23:28:32.515206+00:00 app[web.1]: self.load_wsgi()
2020-06-18T23:28:32.515207+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 144, in load_wsgi
2020-06-18T23:28:32.515207+00:00 app[web.1]: self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
2020-06-18T23:28:32.515220+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
2020-06-18T23:28:32.515221+00:00 app[web.1]: self.callable = self.load()
2020-06-18T23:28:32.515221+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 49, in load
2020-06-18T23:28:32.515221+00:00 app[web.1]: return self.load_wsgiapp()
2020-06-18T23:28:32.515221+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 39, in load_wsgiapp
2020-06-18T23:28:32.515222+00:00 app[web.1]: return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
2020-06-18T23:28:32.515222+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 358, in import_app
2020-06-18T23:28:32.515222+00:00 app[web.1]: mod = importlib.import_module(module)
2020-06-18T23:28:32.515223+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
2020-06-18T23:28:32.515223+00:00 app[web.1]: return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
2020-06-18T23:28:32.515223+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
2020-06-18T23:28:32.515224+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
2020-06-18T23:28:32.515224+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
2020-06-18T23:28:32.515224+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
2020-06-18T23:28:32.515224+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
2020-06-18T23:28:32.515225+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
2020-06-18T23:28:32.515225+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/learning_log/wsgi.py", line 16, in <module>
2020-06-18T23:28:32.515225+00:00 app[web.1]: application = get_wsgi_application()
2020-06-18T23:28:32.515226+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 12, in get_wsgi_application
2020-06-18T23:28:32.515226+00:00 app[web.1]: django.setup(set_prefix=False)
2020-06-18T23:28:32.515226+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 19, in setup
2020-06-18T23:28:32.515227+00:00 app[web.1]: configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)
2020-06-18T23:28:32.515227+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 76, in __getattr__
2020-06-18T23:28:32.515227+00:00 app[web.1]: self._setup(name)
2020-06-18T23:28:32.515227+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 63, in _setup
2020-06-18T23:28:32.515228+00:00 app[web.1]: self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
2020-06-18T23:28:32.515228+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 142, in __init__
2020-06-18T23:28:32.515228+00:00 app[web.1]: mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
2020-06-18T23:28:32.515229+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
2020-06-18T23:28:32.515229+00:00 app[web.1]: return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
2020-06-18T23:28:32.515229+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
2020-06-18T23:28:32.515229+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
2020-06-18T23:28:32.515230+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
2020-06-18T23:28:32.515230+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
2020-06-18T23:28:32.515230+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
2020-06-18T23:28:32.515230+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
2020-06-18T23:28:32.515231+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/learning_log/settings.py", line 134, in <module>
2020-06-18T23:28:32.515231+00:00 app[web.1]: import django_heroku
2020-06-18T23:28:32.515231+00:00 app[web.1]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django_heroku'
2020-06-18T23:28:32.515360+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-06-18 23:28:32 +0000] [10] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 10)
2020-06-18T23:28:32.563252+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2020-06-18T23:28:32.563500+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 209, in run
2020-06-18T23:28:32.563501+00:00 app[web.1]: self.sleep()
2020-06-18T23:28:32.563502+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 357, in sleep
2020-06-18T23:28:32.563503+00:00 app[web.1]: ready = select.select([self.PIPE[0]], [], [], 1.0)
2020-06-18T23:28:32.563503+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 242, in handle_chld
2020-06-18T23:28:32.563509+00:00 app[web.1]: self.reap_workers()
2020-06-18T23:28:32.563509+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 525, in reap_workers
2020-06-18T23:28:32.565281+00:00 app[web.1]: raise HaltServer(reason, self.WORKER_BOOT_ERROR)
2020-06-18T23:28:32.565282+00:00 app[web.1]: gunicorn.errors.HaltServer: <HaltServer 'Worker failed to boot.' 3>
2020-06-18T23:28:32.565283+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-06-18T23:28:32.565283+00:00 app[web.1]: During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
2020-06-18T23:28:32.565284+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-06-18T23:28:32.565294+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2020-06-18T23:28:32.565295+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/bin/gunicorn", line 8, in <module>
2020-06-18T23:28:32.565296+00:00 app[web.1]: sys.exit(run())
2020-06-18T23:28:32.565297+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 58, in run
2020-06-18T23:28:32.565297+00:00 app[web.1]: WSGIApplication("%(prog)s [OPTIONS] [APP_MODULE]").run()
2020-06-18T23:28:32.565298+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 228, in run
2020-06-18T23:28:32.565298+00:00 app[web.1]: super().run()
2020-06-18T23:28:32.565299+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 72, in run
2020-06-18T23:28:32.565299+00:00 app[web.1]: Arbiter(self).run()
2020-06-18T23:28:32.565299+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 229, in run
2020-06-18T23:28:32.565300+00:00 app[web.1]: self.halt(reason=inst.reason, exit_status=inst.exit_status)
2020-06-18T23:28:32.565300+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 342, in halt
2020-06-18T23:28:32.565300+00:00 app[web.1]: self.stop()
2020-06-18T23:28:32.565301+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 393, in stop
2020-06-18T23:28:32.565410+00:00 app[web.1]: time.sleep(0.1)
2020-06-18T23:28:32.565416+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 242, in handle_chld
2020-06-18T23:28:32.565647+00:00 app[web.1]: self.reap_workers()
2020-06-18T23:28:32.565668+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 525, in reap_workers
2020-06-18T23:28:32.565996+00:00 app[web.1]: raise HaltServer(reason, self.WORKER_BOOT_ERROR)
2020-06-18T23:28:32.566074+00:00 app[web.1]: gunicorn.errors.HaltServer: <HaltServer 'Worker failed to boot.' 3>
2020-06-18T23:28:32.635048+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2020-06-18T23:28:32.697976+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2020-06-18T23:32:15.751593+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=frozen-lake-95981.herokuapp.com request_id=a7bcd78a-bc79-4da9-9e8e-102452995106 fwd="37.166.63.85" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-06-18T23:32:16.395228+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=frozen-lake-95981.herokuapp.com request_id=43c7f302-ee9b-41ff-a2a1-db00a6a91134 fwd="37.166.63.85" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Can you confirm if `django_heroku` was installed?, see if this is in your requirements.txt; `django-heroku`.

Comment: Hi Hisham I have updated my request as you can see the package is well installed on my requirements.txt file, I don't know if I am supposed to have so many packages installed as my web app is really simple but I had to download other packages to make django_heroku pip install work

Comment: What do you see in your deploy log when your libraries get installed? Do you also have a `Pipfile` and `Pipfile.lock`?

Comment: (And you probably _don't_ need many of those things. Instead of using `pip freeze` to get all of your installed packages it's generally better to use a virtualenv and add only what you actually need to your requirements file, and install _from that_ locally as well as in production.)

Comment: Hi Chris thanks for your answer! I've modified the post with the code when I check the deploy log don't know if that can help you any further. I've seen on another tread that maybe the problem comes from having both requirements.txt and Pipfile but I don't really get where I am supposed to check for Pipfile or Pipfile.lock

Comment: That's not your deploy log, that's your runtime log. Your deploy log is what you see when you run `git push heroku`. On the `Pipfile` front, do you have a file with that name in the root directory of your project?

Comment: When I run git push heroku I get "Everything up to date", and in the root directory I have db.sqlite3 manage.py Procfile requirements.txt and runtime.txt but no Pipfile...

Comment: Okay, well the previous `git push` would have shown a bunch more information. The version of `requirements.txt` you've committed includes the `django-heroku==0.3.1` line? That's not just a local change? Run [`heroku releases`](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/releases#listing-release-history) and make sure the deployed commit hash is what you expect.

Comment: Yes my requirements.txt includes==0.3.1 line, that's what I get when I run heroku releases.

Comment: frozen-lake-95981 Releases - Current: v6
v6  Deploy f54…  loccialexandre@gmail.com  2020/06/18 22:58:55 +0200 (~ 15h ago)
v5  @ref:postg…  loccialexandre@gmail.com  2020/06/18 22:58:55 +0200 (~ 15h ago)
v4  Attach DAT…  loccialexandre@gmail.com  2020/06/18 22:58:54 +0200 (~ 15h ago)
v3  Set DISABL…  loccialexandre@gmail.com  2020/06/18 22:57:58 +0200 (~ 15h ago)
v2  Enable Log…  loccialexandre@gmail.com  2020/06/18 16:18:35 +0200 (~ 22h ago)
v1  Initial re…  loccialexandre@gmail.com  2020/06/18 16:18:35 +0200 (~ 22h ago)

Answer (score 2):

Use the following commands:

```
pip install psycopg2-binary
pip install django-on-heroku
```

After installation, look for the folder **django_on_heroku-1.0.1.dist-info**, read for more info in the **METADATA** file.

The two lines of code to be added into `setting.py` are:

```
import django_on_heroku
django_on_heroku.settings(locals())
```